# Customizer: CSS changes not persistent

Tags: css, theme-customizer

Customizer API is saving HTML/data changes properly but any CSS change is only visible in the Customizer. After hitting "Save & Publish" the page is exactly like it used to be with no new `<style>` tags in the `<head>`. This is the way I declare customizer controls and settings in functions.php (mind you this is not the complete code).

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('design-header-background-color', array(
    'default' => '#ffffff',
));
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'design-header-background-color', array(
    'label' => __( 'Background color' ),
    'section' => 'design-header',
    'priority' => 10
)));
function design_header_background_color()
{
    ?>
         <style type="text/css">
             header { background-color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('design-header-background-color'); ?>; }
         </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'design_header_background_color');
```

When I use the control in the Customizer I can see stuff changing properly. But after using "Save & Publish" nothing happens. As I said HTML/PHP manipulations work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Even though I wasn't able to figure it out with CSS and wp_head() I managed to hack something that works.

```
<?php
    $sidebar_background_color = get_theme_mod('design-sidebar-background-color');
?>

<aside style="background-color: <?php $sidebar_background_color; ?>;">
    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar() ) : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</aside>
```

Since I could manipulate DOM and HTML just fine I decided to change CSS "manually" as inline styling. It works though the method feels superhacky.

v2 with `<style></style>` block.

```
<?php
    $header_background_color = get_theme_mod('design-header-background-color');
    $header_background_image = get_theme_mod('design-header-background-image');

?>

<style> /* FOR CUSTOMIZER API ONLY, DON'T CUSTOMIZE CSS HERE */
    <?php if (get_theme_mod('design-header-css') === '') : ?>
        header .page-header {
            background-color: <?php echo $header_background_color; ?>;
            background-image: url('<?php echo $header_background_image; ?>');
        }
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php echo get_theme_mod('design-header-css'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</style>

<!--- HTML GOES HERE -->
```

Comment: It works even better when I use `<style></style>` block. Clears things up.